# I want to calculate maximum variance according to the sales with storetype

Tags: r

I am a beginner in **R**. I have dataset with 11 column and 3000 `obs`.
The data frame has 3000 `obs` and 11 columns. There are 6 columns of various sales and I want to measure the variance in each sale column across store_Type:

```
table(s1$store_Type)
Grocery Store Supermarket Type1 Supermarket Type2 Supermarket Type3 
          242              1226               200               350
```

I am not sure how to start to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate variance on a data set you can use var(). To calculate by columns, use apply(). For example:

```
# create fake data
set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(15,100,200), ncol = 3, nrow = 5))
colnames(dat) <-c("Store 1", "Store 2", "Store 3")

# generate variance 
var.dat <-apply(dat, MARGIN=2, FUN=var) # by column

var.dat
Store 1  Store 2  Store 3 
866.3951 914.2388 978.7129
```

Answer (score 0):

I used tapply() to find the individual variance for different sales. Then I summed up the variance for individual store type to get the variance. Thought of grouping by Store Type but couldn't get the result. Eventhough, I got the answer, felt mechanical doing it. There must be another way of doing this.!

```
v2 = tapply(store_train$sales1,store_train$store_Type, var)
v3 = tapply(store_train$sales2,store_train$store_Type, var)
v4 = tapply(store_train$sales3,store_train$store_Type, var)
v5 = tapply(store_train$sales4,store_train$store_Type, var)
 
v1[1] + v2[1] + v3[1] + v4[1] + v5[1]
v1[2] + v2[2] + v3[2] + v4[2] + v5[2]
v1[3] + v2[3] + v3[3] + v4[3] + v5[3]
v1[4] + v2[4] + v3[4] + v4[4] + v5[4]
```